# Export expandable table to CSV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

There is an expandable table in HTML:

```
<table width="900" id="mytable">
      <tr>
        <th>Cost Category</th>
        <th>Costs</th>
      </tr>
<tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0" bgcolor="#A2D9CE">
    <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span> First row</td>
    <td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1" bgcolor="#D5F5E3">
    <td><span class="toggle"></span> Second row</td>
    <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2" bgcolor="#D6EAF8">
    <td><span class="toggle"></span> Third row</td>
    <td>250</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I export it to CSV while keeping the structure--expandable table?

Update: the table looks like this:
[image]

Comment: what you mean by expandable table ? can you try creating a demo

Comment: Updated the question: with collapse and toggle: sub rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent this table data in a CSV, you will need a "Depth" column in addition to the "Cost Category" and "Cost" columns in the CSV.

See the code below.

```js
const csv = [];
$("#mytable").find("tr").each((index, row) => {
  const category = $(row).find("th,td").eq(0).text().trim();
  const cost = $(row).find("th,td").eq(1).text().trim();
  const depth = $(row).data("depth") || (index === 0 ? "Depth" : 0);
  csv.push([category, cost, depth].join(", "));
});
console.log(csv.join("\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="900" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Cost Category</th>
    <th>Costs</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0" bgcolor="#A2D9CE">
    <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span> First row</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1" bgcolor="#D5F5E3">
    <td><span class="toggle"></span> Second row</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-depth="2" class="collapse level2" bgcolor="#D6EAF8">
    <td><span class="toggle"></span> Third row</td>
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```